# Github desktop custom color scheme

Tags: github-desktop

Is it possible to set custom color scheme for github desktop app? So yes, there are light and dark options in the menu, but I mean playing with the color tones of the dark theme.

What I want to achieve is to apply the monokai color scheme. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Github Docs go, currently there are only light and dark themes available.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/desktop/installing-and-configuring-github-desktop/configuring-and-customizing-github-desktop/setting-a-theme-for-github-desktop

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I've looked there before. I'll wait in case there is some kind of hack. Otherwise I will confirm your answer.